# Powershell add text to start, end of output file

Tags: powershell, parsing

I have a folder containing multiple text files that I am combining into one file. On that output file I need to add a string to the top and the bottom of the file. I have tried using insert and I keep getting an error. The file is contained in the $Output variable

My code so far:

```
if(!(Test-Path -Path $PathDump)) {
    # create the folder if it does not yet exist
    New-Item -ItemType Directory $PathDump
}
# move all *.txt items from 'C:\RemoveFirst\txt' to 'C:\RemoveFirst\DumpARoo'
# EXCEPT the output file itself

$Path = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*.txt' -File).FullName | Where-Object { $_ -ne $Output}
Move-Item -Path $Path -Destination $PathDump # move (not copy) files into new directory to concat
Get-ChildItem -Path $PathDump -Filter '*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object {
    '' # Output an empty line at SOF
    '---------------------------------------------------------------'
    $_ | Get-Content | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 
    '---------------------------------------------------------------' 
    '' # Output an empty line at EOF
}   | Add-Content -Path $OutPut
```

Comment: Sorry about that! I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The story continues ;)

Try this:

```
$Path     = 'C:\RemoveFirst\*.txt'
$PathDump = 'C:\RemoveFirst\DumpARoo'
$Output   = 'C:\RemoveFirst\TestingFile.txt'

if(!(Test-Path -Path $PathDump)) {
    # create the folder if it does not yet exist
    New-Item -ItemType Directory $PathDump
}
# move all *.txt items from 'C:\RemoveFirst\txt' to 'C:\RemoveFirst\DumpARoo'
# EXCEPT the output file itself

$Path = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*.txt' -File).FullName | Where-Object { $_ -ne $Output}
Move-Item -Path $Path -Destination $PathDump # move (not copy) files into new directory to concat

# Output 'SOF'
"SOF" | Add-Content -Path $OutPut
Get-ChildItem -Path $PathDump -Filter '*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object {
    # output the content of the current file
    $_ | Get-Content | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 | Add-Content -Path $OutPut
}  
# Output 'EOF'
"EOF" | Add-Content -Path $OutPut
```

Comment: Right now I have a dashed line at the beginning and end of each individual text file that is merged into the output but in the actual output file I need SOF at the beginning and EOF at the end

Comment: @GarrettStarkey Ok, if you don't want the dashed line, just do `"SOF" | Add-Content -Path $OutPut`, then the content and lastly `"EOF" | Add-Content -Path $OutPut`. You can be as creative with this as you like.

Comment: I understand now, I read it completely wrong! That is it for this series :) Thank you

Comment: Actually it doesn't work...I'm not looking for it to say SOF and EOF for each individual file I want it to say that for the one big file when all said and done

Comment: @GarrettStarkey Ah, then move `"SOF" | Add-Content -Path $OutPut` to above the `Get-ChildItem -Path $PathDump ...` line and `"EOF" | Add-Content -Path $OutPut` to below the last closing bracket `}`

Comment: @GarrettStarkey For clarity I have changed that in the answer.